# Is it possible to have a non-rectangular div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I need to shape **ONE** `div` tag in the following shape:

[image]

Is it possible to make it cross browser? I don't necessarily need rounded corners. I need it so I can change the color of the borders of the whole `div` on hover, so I assume it can't be achieved by using two `div`s.

Comment: Do you need it to size with its content?

Comment: You can do most of what you're after, as illustrated in my answer below.  The main constraint, as others have pointed out, is going to be in the ability to flow text in the region you've drawn.

There are also solutions involving an SVG-background image, or overlaying a transparent div on top of a <canvas> element, and other tricks like that, but for straight up vanilla HTML + CSS that has a prayer of working "cross browser", I'm pretty sure the solution I provide is about as close as you're gonna get.

Answer (score 12):

Yeah, you can do that using HTML and CSS like this: http://jsfiddle.net/broofa/364Eq/

It's essentially using three divs to aggregate the mouse events, like so:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

And I use a :hover rule on the outer element to affect the border colors on the inner divs:

```
#outer .inner {border-color: red}
#outer:hover .inner {border-color: blue}
```

The only quirk with this markup is that the content area - the area you drew in your image - is that it's two divs, not one.  So text won't wrap and flow the way you might expect.  Also, this may not work so well on older (IE6-7) browsers.  But FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera should probably be okay.

Answer (score 3):

A one div solution using pseudo elements:

```css
/* relevant styles for shape */
.tab {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.tab:before {
  content:"";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  right: 52px; /* width + border width */
  top: -2px;
  background-color: white;
  border: inherit;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

/* styles to look like example */
div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div:hover {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/QYk5z/4/):

```
<div id="main">    
    <div id="div1" class="border">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="border">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a map or use 2 divs and alter the borders so it looks like one shape.

Answer (score 1):

two options that I can think of:

1) give the div a background image and use CSS pseudo class :hover to change the background image to one that indicates a hover state

2) put three div's inside a wrapper, and position them so so you have one in the upper left hand corner, and then two stacked on top of each other, so that you can simulate the top half of a larger div missing the upper left half border.  I don't think CSS alonw can target all the divs in order to change their borders, so will probably have to use JS to execute the hover behavior, by applying an event handler to all three divs.

Comment: I'd go with #1 here - it's probably the most straightforward solution to this. Alternatively you could probably use an SVG shape, but that's probably a bit more complex (plus won't work in older browsers, etc.)

Comment: as for #2, others have provided a 2 div solution which would work as well.

Comment: Re: #1, Using background images is _fail_.  Very difficult to apply different colors, requires loading extra resources for the page... just generally a bad idea.

Re #2, answer is just wrong.  :hover on the outer DIV works (see jsfiddle example in my answer)

Comment: @broofa: um...how is a background image on a div a 'fail', or hard to implement?  one image for on state, one image for off state.  granted an extra HTTP request, but doesn't it make up for the fact that you have less complicated markup, and have more control over the inside of the div?  doesn't seem appropriate to downvote just because it's a different solution than yours....

Comment: and with an image you can easily have rounded corners, or make any side any color you want.

Comment: @thescientist: Background image requires loading at least one or more extra images into the page which impacts load time. Images don't resize.  Images are much harder to maintain if you ever decide to change the look (color, border width, radius, background color, whatever).  You have to keep your original photoshop files (or whatever) around so you can make that change.  You can't experiment with styling in-browser (via Firebug or Web Inspector) the way you can with CSS... to name a few reasons why they're fail. :)

Comment: @broofa: that's just like, you're opinion man.  whatever you thinks works best, ultimately it's up the OP.  I don't see the harm in one image, sprited, to achieve a rounded corners image with any possible color and shape combinations, that also gives you more free reign within the div element itself.  horses for courses.

Answer (score 1):

No. Divs are ALWAYS rectangular. You could fake it in a number of ways (using a background image would be one option).

As for using two DIVs, sure you could. The hover could be done with CSS3 and child selectors of a parent div or you could JavaScript to change the class of both divs when hovering over either one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely requires two or three div's unless you use a background image

Here's a three-div solution

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/SUuF6/

Its cross-browser compatible. The hover won't work in IE6, but it will in IE7+. The rounded corners will show based on browser support

**HTML:**

```
<div id="fancyShape">
    <div id="main">&lt;div&gt;</div>
    <div id="panHandle"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#fancyShape {position:relative;width:504px;height:304px;}

#main {
    margin-left:100px;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    border:solid 2px #000;
    border-radius:0 15px 15px 15px;

}
#panHandle {
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
    border-top:solid 2px #000;
    border-left:solid 2px #000;
    border-bottom:solid 2px #000;
    border-radius:15px 0 0 15px;
}

/* hover effect */
#fancyShape div {background-color:#fff;}
#fancyShape:hover div {background-color:#ff0;border-color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [Border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) along with 2 or 3 div's to get the look you want. The only issue then is it's not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple divs, as others have suggested.

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/7B5MA/14/

Keep in mind that it'll be very hard to flow content in this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>

 <style>
 html{height: 100%; width: 100%;}
 body{height: 100%; width: 100%;}

 #wrapper{
 position: relative;
 top: 50px;
 right: 25%;
 width: 565px;
 height: 440px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
 }
 #left{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-right: none;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px; 
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 }
 #right{
 position: absolute;
 left: 100px;
 width: 440px;
 height: 440px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 }
 </style>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#wrapper').hover(
   function () {
  $(this).children('#left').css({'border':'2px solid red', 'border-right':'none'});
  $(this).children('#right').css({'border':'2px solid red'});
  }, 
  function () {
  $(this).children('#left').css({'border':'2px solid black', 'border-right':'none'});
  $(this).children('#right').css({'border':'2px solid black'});
 });
 });
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="right">Some content here</div>
 <div id = "left"></div>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

You can use CSSPIE for rounded orners for IE

Comment: After looking at broofa's answer I'd say using class for hover instead of IDs makes much more sense.