# Is it possible to have non-rectangular or transparent frames in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transparency, frame

I want to have a widget, which includes flash, and which works continuously on page navigation. So, I need to use `<frameset>`.

Is it possible to assign any other geometry to the frames, except rectangular margins of the page?

Comment: Your conclusion that you need to use a `<frameset>` is not necessarily correct.

Comment: You can load new content on a page in many ways. You can use `<iframe>` elements, for example, or use AJAX to load content into just about any type of container element. That doesn't address the non-rectangular issue, but then that's a problem with current browser capabilities in general.

Comment: This looks wrong. Both `<iframe>` and ajax loads will stop and kill flash animation on page leave. The only way I found to keep it -- is normal frames.

Comment: ??? I don't think that's true at all, but I'm not a flash programmer.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncsyH/1/) that's got flash in an `<iframe>` and an AJAX request (click the button).  Flash keeps going for me.

Comment: You are changing only date/time. While my requirement is to navigate from page to page keeping flash running uninterrupted.

Comment: It's changing the date/time by making an AJAX request to the server. But whatever, do what you want. Nobody codes `<frameset>` pages nowadays by the way. Nobody.

Comment: Yes I know, I just looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement what you can do is that pub div inside the frameset and you can apply styles on div as you like, but as far as i know frameset is rectangular only.Check this for non rectangular div.

[Is it possible to have a non-rectangular div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444129/is-it-possible-to-have-a-non-rectangular-div)